# Passing different parameters to an overloaded operator function

Tags: c++, function, class, operator-overloading

I currently have a class called Complex:

```
class Complex{
public:
    Complex();
    Complex(double, double);
    double r, i;
    void read(istream &in);
    void display(ostream &out) const;
    double real, imaginary;
```

That I am using to overload the addition operator. Currently I have three separate function declarations to handle 3 different cases: 2 complex numbers, 1 complex number and 1 int on the right, and 1 int and 1 complex number on the right.

```
Complex operator+ (const Complex& num1, const Complex& num2);
Complex operator+ (const int num1, const Complex& num2);
Complex operator+ (const Complex& num1,const int num2);
```

The function declarations all just add up the "real" and "imaginary" parts of complex numbers and add the integers to the real parts of the complex numbers.

```
Complex operator+ (const Complex& num1,const Complex& num2) {
    Complex result;
    result.real += num1.real + num2.real;
    result.imaginary += num1.imaginary +num2.imaginary;
    return result;
}
Complex operator+ (const int num1, const Complex& num2){
    Complex result;
    result.real += num1;
    result.imaginary += num2.imaginary;
    return result;
}
Complex operator+ (const Complex& num1, const int num2){
    Complex result;
    result.real += num2;
    result.imaginary += num1.imaginary;
    return result;
}
```

There has to be a better way to do this right? Or do all three cases have to be explicitly declared?

Comment: What is `double r, i;` for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a delegating constructor to your `Complex` class.

```
class Complex{
public:
    Complex();
    Complex(double, double);

    Complex(double a) : Complex(a, 0) {}
```

Then you will find that you need to define only one `operator+`:

```
Complex operator+(const Complex &a, const Complex &b);
```

And it will handle all the use cases in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the code inside your functions is unnecessarily complicated. You definitely should be initializing `result` using its two-argument constructor, instead of initializing to zero and then modifying. For example the code could have been:

```
Complex operator+ (const Complex& num1,const Complex& num2)
{
    return Complex(num1.real + num2.real, num1.imaginary + num2.imaginary);
}

Complex operator+ (const Complex& num1, const int num2)
{
    return Complex(num1.real + num2, num1.imaginary);
}

Complex operator+ (const int num1, const Complex& num2)
{
    return num2 + num1;    // compiler will inline this
}
```

I'm not sure why you used `int` here, it seems better all round to use `double`.

---

Sam's answer shows how you can reduce three functions to 1. That reduces the amount of typing you have to do, although it does introduce a slight performance reduction: you end up doing an extra `+ 0.0` on the return value's `imaginary`.

If we look ahead to multiplication then this penalty is a little bit more severe, for example the code:

```
Complex operator*(Complex const &lhs, double rhs)
{
    return Complex(lhs.real * rhs, lhs.imaginary * rhs);
}
```

is many fewer operations than than the code inside `Complex operator*(Complex const &lhs, Complex const &rhs)` would do.

So you have to make this choice between code simplicity and performance.